# Pytorch: Convert FloatTensor into DoubleTensor

Tags: python, torch, pytorch

I have 2 numpy arrays, which I convert into tensors to use the TensorDataset object.

```
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

X = np.zeros((100,30))
Y = np.zeros((100,30))

train = data_utils.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X).double(), torch.from_numpy(Y))
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)
```

when I do:

```
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(data)               # error occurs here
```

I get the fallowing error:

> TypeError: addmm_ received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, int, torch.DoubleTensor, torch.FloatTensor), but expected one of:
>    [...]
>    * (float beta, float alpha, torch.DoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
>         didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (int, int, torch.DoubleTensor, torch.FloatTensor)
>    * (float beta, float alpha, torch.SparseDoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
>         didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (int, int, torch.DoubleTensor, torch.FloatTensor)

The last error comes from:

> output.addmm_(0, 1, input, weight.t())

As you see in my code I tried converting the tensor by using .double() - but this did not work. Why is he casting one array into a FloatTensor object and the other into a DoubleTensor?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `numpy` arrays are `64-bit floating point` and will be converted to `torch.DoubleTensor` standardly. Now, if you use them with your model, you'll need to make sure that your model parameters are also `Double`. Or you need to make sure, that your `numpy` arrays are cast as `Float`, because model parameters are standardly cast as `float`.

Hence, do either of the following:

```
data_utils.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X).float(), torch.from_numpy(Y).float())
```

or do:

```
model.double()
```

Depeding, if you want to cast your model parameters, inputs and targets as `Float` or as `Double`.

Answer (score 7):

This is because in PyTorch, you can not do operations between Tensor of different types. Your `data` is `DoubleTensor`, but the model parameter are `FloatTensor`. So you get this error message. As @mexmex have said, convert `data` to `FloatTensor` to make it conform with the model parameter type.

**Do not do the other way around!** [**Trying to convert the model to double is greatly discouraged by PyTorch devs**](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/problems-with-target-arrays-of-int-int32-types-in-loss-functions/140/3) as GPUs are not good at double precision computation. Also, floating point is pretty enough for deep learning.