# How to train pytorch model with numpy data and batch size?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am learning the basics of pytorch and thought to create a simple 4 layer nerual network with dropout to train IRIS dataset for classification. After refering to many tutorials I wrote this code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

epochs=300
batch_size=20
lr=0.01

#loading data as numpy array
data = load_iris()
X=data.data
y=pd.get_dummies(data.target).values

#convert to tensor
X= Variable(torch.from_numpy(X), requires_grad=False)
y=Variable(torch.from_numpy(y), requires_grad=False)
print(X.size(),y.size())

#neural net model
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(4, 10),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Dropout(),
    torch.nn.Linear(10, 5),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Dropout(),
    torch.nn.Linear(5, 3),
    torch.nn.Softmax()
)

print(model)

# Loss and Optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)  
loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  

for i in range(epochs):
    # Forward pass
    y_pred = model(X)

    # Compute and print loss.
    loss = loss_func(y_pred, y)
    print(i, loss.data[0])

    # Before the backward pass, use the optimizer object to zero all of the
    # gradients for the variables it will update (which are the learnable weights
    # of the model)
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()

    # Calling the step function on an Optimizer makes an update to its parameters
    optimizer.step()
```

There are currently two problems I am facing.

1. I want to set a batch size of `20`. How should I do this?
2. At this step `y_pred = model(X)` its showing this error

Error

```
 TypeError: addmm_ received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, int, torch.DoubleTensor, torch.FloatTensor), but expected one of:
 * (torch.DoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
 * (torch.SparseDoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
 * (float beta, torch.DoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
 * (float alpha, torch.DoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
 * (float beta, torch.SparseDoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
 * (float alpha, torch.SparseDoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
 * (float beta, float alpha, torch.DoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (int, int, torch.DoubleTensor, !torch.FloatTensor!)
 * (float beta, float alpha, torch.SparseDoubleTensor mat1, torch.DoubleTensor mat2)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (int, int, !torch.DoubleTensor!, !torch.FloatTensor!)
```

Comment: do you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry I could not solve this problem. If you have a solution please post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to set a batch size of 20. How should I do this?

For data processing and loading, PyTorch provide two classes, one is [`Dataset`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset), which is used to represent your dataset. Specifically, `Dataset` provide the interface to get one sample from the whole dataset using the sample index.

But `Dataset` is not enough, for large dataset, we need to do batch processing. So PyTorch provide a second class [`Dataloader`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), which is used to generate batches from the `Dataset` given the batch size and other parameters.

For your specific case, I think you should try [`TensorDataset`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset). Then use a `Dataloader` to set batch size to 20. Just look through the PyTorch [official examples](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py#L37) to get a sense how to do it.

> At this step y_pred = model(X) its showing this error

The error message is pretty informative. Your input `X` to the model is type `DoubleTensor`. But your model parameters have type `FloatTensor`. In PyTorch, you can not do operation between Tensors of different types. What you should do is replace the line

```
X= Variable(torch.from_numpy(X), requires_grad=False)
```

with

```
X= Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).float(), requires_grad=False)
```

Now, `X` has type `FloatTensor`, the error message should disappear.

Also, as a gentle reminder, there are pretty much materials on the Internet about your question which can sufficiently solve your problem. You should try hard to solve it by yourself.

Comment: Now its showing this error `TypeError: FloatClassNLLCriterion_updateOutput received an invalid combination of`. If its ok can you share the fully solved codes. For the past two months I am stuck here and could not able to gain any knolwedge in pytorch past this. Sometimes we will get stuck in places where we cant seem to find a solution and I am currently in this position. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please update your code, then I will find what is wrong with your code. I have tried to run myself, it works fine.  The loss decreases as training goes, see [here](https://ibb.co/kQH0TR)

Answer (score 1):

Probably same issue: [Pytorch: Convert FloatTensor into DoubleTensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717100/pytorch-convert-floattensor-into-doubletensor?rq=1)

In short: when converting from numpy the values are stored in DoubleTensor, while optimizer requires FloatTensor. You have to change one of them.